# Update ECS cluster from Jenkins using AWSCLI

Tags: jenkins, aws-cli, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have ECS fargate cluster.I am working on CICD to push images to ECR repository and then update the cluster.I am using latest tag in my repositories.

By using below way i used to do it manually.
Create new version of task definition ----> Update the service with new version of task definition ---> Stop the task with old version.

Now when i am trying to automate this from Jenkins i am using AWSCLI.

I have one question.If i use below command will it create a new version of task definition and update service ? OR i have to create a new version of task definition first.

```
  aws ecs update-service --cluster ec2cluster_name --service service_name --force-new-deployment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are updating/using the same image tag then when you do `forceNewDeployment` it will fetch the latest image from the repository and updates the ECS service.

The ecs-update-service documentation says:

> If your updated Docker image uses the same tag as what is in the existing task definition for your service (for example, my_image:latest ), you do not need to create a new revision of your task definition. You can update the service using the forceNewDeployment option. The new tasks launched by the deployment pull the current image/tag combination from your repository when they start.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html

The above command will not create new task definition and to create a task definciiton have a look at [register-task-definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/register-task-definition.html)

Comment: I use the same image tag (latest).SO if i understand it correct here i dont have to create new version of task definition.Above mentioned commnd is fine right ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Just updating the ecs-service with force-new-deployment would suffice for your case.